# which version of eclipse to use with app engine java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry for being a MS dev :)

what version of eclipse do I need to use with app engine (java)?

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the latest release Galileo (3.5.1). [See the docs for instructions](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html),

> The plugin is available for Eclipse versions 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from Classic pack with 3.5.1 version and install all needed plugins in there later using instructions [here](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.5.html)